# ASP.NET - Drop down menu won't load

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Alright, so I've researched to no avail about this problem, but nothing I try works.
The web pages in my main directory can pull down the drop down menu just fine. However, I have web pages in a folder (along with an identical header.html file in the folder) that references the local header.html inside the folder and the drop down menu does NOT pull down. I've tried everything I could think of. I even took the contents out of the header.html and inserted directly onto the aspx page but the drop down menu still didn't pull down. Please advise.

Here's where I load bootstrap and css:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

        <!-- Load JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery/jquery.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/prettify/prettify.js") %>"></script>


    <!-- Metro UI CSS JavaScript plugins -->
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/load-metro.js") %>"></script>

    <!-- Local JavaScript -->
    <script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/docs.js") %>"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap stylesheets. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/metro-bootstrap-temple.css")%>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/metro-bootstrap-responsive-temple.css")%>" />

    <link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/prettify/prettify.css")%>" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!--Special icons! -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/css/iconFont.css")%>" />
</head>
<body class="metro">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <!-- This code uses a function in docs.js to load the header content from a separate file. -->
        <header class="bg-templecherry" data-load="header.html"></header>
```

Here's my header:

```
<nav class="navigation-bar temple">
    <nav class="navigation-bar-content container">
        <!--Title-->
        <a href="index.aspx" class="element"><span class="icon-film"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VERTOV <sup>ALPHA</sup></a>
        <!--Divider-->
        <span class="element-divider"></span>



        <a class="element1 pull-menu" href="#"></a>
            <ul class="element-menu">

         <!--Search-->
                <li>
                    <a href="search.aspx" class="element">SEARCH</a>
                </li>

        <!--Upload-->
                <li>
                    <a href="upload.aspx" class="element">UPLOAD</a>
                </li>
        <!--Queue-->
                <li>
                    <a href="queue.aspx" class="element">QUEUE</a>
                </li>

        <!--Manage-->
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">MANAGE</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dark" data-role="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="accounts.aspx">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="managedefaulttags.aspx">DEFAULT TAGS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="shotsRequiringTagging.aspx">UNTAGGED SHOTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="suggestedTags.aspx">SUGGESTED TAGS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="UploadHistory.aspx">UPLOAD HISTORY</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

        <!--Logout-->
                <li>
                    <a href="index.aspx" class="element place-right">LOGOUT</a>
                </li>                    

            </ul>

    </nav>
</nav>
```

Here's what's in the doc.js file:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-load]").each(function(){
        $(this).load($(this).data("load"), function(){
        });
    });

    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();

    $(".history-back").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        history.back();
        return false;
    })
})


$(document).ready(function headerPosition(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('header').height()) {
        $("header .navigation-bar")
            .addClass("fixed-top")
            .addClass(" shadow")
        ;
    } else {
        $("header .navigation-bar")
            .removeClass("fixed-top")
            .removeClass(" shadow")
        ;
    }
}
)
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('nav > .side-menu').length > 0) {
        var side_menu = $('nav > .side-menu');
        var fixblock_pos = side_menu.position().top;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > fixblock_pos){
                side_menu.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top':'65px', 'z-index':'1000'});
            } else {
                side_menu.css({'position': 'static'});
            }
        })
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){headerPosition();}, 100);
})

$(window).scroll(function(){
    headerPosition();
});

METRO_AUTO_REINIT = true;
```

I'm not sure if I should include other .js stuff since the drop down menu works for pages in the main directory, just not when pages are in folders. I used the Page.ResolveURL to remedy any issues but this one still remains.

Comment: Tried to wrap it in $(document).ready(function () { ... }); ?

Comment: @PabloLemurr I did as you said, updated the code in my original post. The drop down menu still doesn't pull down. :(

Comment: Can you open a console (F12) and tell if there are any errors?

Comment: @PabloLemurr Interesting! I found this in the developer console.
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
jquery.min.js, line 3 character 4231
SCRIPT5009: 'headerPosition' is undefined 
docs.js, line 46 character 27

but, web pages in the main directory read the same docs.js file and it works. It just doesn't work in the sub directories?

Comment: The synatx error in the jquery.min.js doesn't show up when I run the console on one of the pages in the main directory, so I guess this is the problem, even though all the pages reference this same file. But the jquery.min.js file is jargon to me,I don't know how to fix the syntax error.

Comment: Try to download jquery.min.js from the website http://jquery.com/download/ again - it might got corrupted